# getting data for individual months using single query

Tags: sql, oracle

Im having 3 tables as per below picture (im giving just sample data but actual tables having data for all months). My SALES table will contain the data both for future(which were sold in future) and past dates.

```
select  item_id as agg from item_category f JOIN 
sales t ON f.item_id=t.item_id where t.selling_date
BETWEEN sysdate AND sysdate+21 and f.item_type='medicine';
```

and now my query returns ITEMS which were sold for next 21 days. Now i want to get the profit of these ITEMS for past one year
For example i want the profit for last one year as Jan:2000,feb:3000,mar:1000.......
[image]

Comment: You already asked this question today.  Deleting and reposting won't accomplish much unless you've fixed the reason why you couldn't get an answer before.

Answer (score 0):

You could group items by date of sale and aggregate this profit.

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(sold_date) AS `Year`,
    MONTH(sold_date) AS `Month`,
    SUM(profit) AS Profit
FROM sales JOIN Reventue_Table ON sales.item_id=Reventue_Table.item_id
GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`;
```

If you want to get result for specific year, use `HAVING` clause. For SQL use [DATEPART()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp) function. For oracle use [EXTRACT()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm).

Comment: `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` are not Oracle functions.

Answer (score 0):

To get the output in rows:

```
SELECT -- s.item_id,                           -- Not sure if you want it total or per item
       TRUNC( s.sold_date, 'MM' ) AS sold_month,
       SUM( r.profit ) AS total_profit
FROM   sales s
       INNER JOIN
       revenue_table r
       ON ( s.item_id = r.item_id )
GROUP BY -- s.item_id,                         -- Not sure if you want it total or per item
       TRUNC( s.sold_date, 'MM' )
```

To `PIVOT` the rows into columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT -- s.item_id,                         -- Not sure if you want it total or per item
         TRUNC( s.sold_date, 'MM' ) AS sold_month,
         r.profit
  FROM   sales s
         INNER JOIN
         revenue_table r
         ON ( s.item_id = r.item_id )
)
PIVOT ( SUM( profit ) FOR sold_month IN (
  DATE '2017-05-01' AS May2017,
  DATE '2017-04-01' AS Apr2017,
  DATE '2017-03-01' AS Mar2017,
  DATE '2017-02-01' AS Feb2017,
  DATE '2017-01-01' AS Jan2017,
  DATE '2016-12-01' AS Dec2016,
  DATE '2016-11-01' AS Nov2016,
  DATE '2016-10-01' AS Oct2016
) )
```